# android application color display real-time

Tags: android, colors

I do not even know where to begin on this.

I want to know how to illuminate a region of the screen on my application so that I can write code that will display certain colors depending on what the user does. I have looked at questions asked by other users but most of them deal with the theme of the application which involves creating specific files. I do not want to change the theme. I want to display a color in a region of the screen. Perhaps there is a command that will allow me to specify specific pixels on the screen and illuminate them to be the color that I want. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the layout xml file of this activity. set the background of this view. (The view you want to set the color)

Comment: That will not give me real-time control will it? I want the color to change as the user manipulates the app

Comment: if you want to do it real time. you can use view. setBackgroundColor() method. view can be other types of views you created. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29

Comment: How do I select which view to use with the setBackgroundColor() method? I tried it with just "view" and I think that is referring to something else because nothing changes